# Using Google Sheets for web scraping. Need the correct xpath for IMPORTXML function

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is a google sheet containing a list of MPN's (manufacturer part numbers). Trying to scrape a site called wikiarms for the UPC Codes when I have the MPN for an item.

I have the correct formula for doing this on another site.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/"&B1,"//dd/a[../../dt[contains(text(),'UPC')]]|//dd/span[../../dt[contains(text(),'UPC')]]")
```

Trying to figure out what the correct xpath to complete this formula. Some videos I have watch said to open the page in Chrome and use inspector to select and copy the xpath to complete the importxml function.  I tried this with no luck.

Sample
Visit https://www.wikiarms.com/guns?q=20071

In the table there is a button "available in 6 stores" click that to reveal the list. The UPC should be listed after the MPN.

If I copy the xpath in Chrome this is the result

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]

=IMPORTXML("https://www.wikiarms.com/guns?q="&B2,"xpath here")
```

What do I have to add at the end of this formula to pull in the UPC code? I will be using this formula to pull in UPC code for about 1000 items.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample link, try

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.wikiarms.com/guns?q=20071","//td[@class='upc']/a/@title")
```

and see if it works for you.